# How to parse a JSON string that contains u' characters?

Tags: json.net

I'm trying to parse a JSON string below:

```
\"result\": \"[{u'p_ssn': u'111451234', u'_id': '4e47e811c19a830ff9009011', u'p_hdistrict': u'U',...
```

Is there any easy way to parse this in .NET and get resulting object/data-structure that I can use further?

I tried JSON.NET's JObject.Parse() method but it throws an exception.

Comment: It seems to be the [unicode literal](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) of python... But I don't know why it's there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

try json.dumps() from here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

```
data = {u'p_ssn': u'111451234', u'_id': '4e47e811c19a830ff9009011', u'p_hdistrict': u'U',...}

print json.dumps(data['p_ssn'])

'>>>["111451234"]
```